# MongoDB joining user and likes collection based on reference ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a little social network using ExpressJS and MongoDB. I have a little problem relating to likes and posts collection. I know you can embed a `likes` inside a `posts` collection, but I have decided to separate both of the collection and use reference ids so I can join them later on. The main problem I have currently is this, how do I include the `likes` reference on the `posts` collection?

Let's say my `posts` schema looks something like this:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  isLiked: false, 
}, { timestamps: true });
```

and my `likes` schema looks something like this:

```
const LikeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    // The user who is liking the post.
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
    },

    // The post that is being liked.
    question: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Question',
      required: true
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

I wanna make it so that whenever I try to query the posts collection, I can also get the likes embedded in it by referencing the collection and not modifying the schema to have embedded `likes` in it.

An example response:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("test"), 
  content: 'A post', 
  isLiked: false, 
  likes: ["A user object here based on the `likes collection`"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain them before sending the response:

1. Find all the likes of that post, something similar to `Like.find({ question: <postId> })`
2. Then you can resolve the users of that likes, in the command above you can concatenate `.populate('user')` with the [mongoose populate feature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)
3. If you are interested only to the user object and not the entire like object, you can extract resolved user: `const users = likes.map(x => x.user)`
4. Then you can add the users array to the post object and sending the final object as response